# Is there a good notion of kernels of quadratic forms on abelian groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, quadratic-forms, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $q:G \to \mathbb{Q/Z}$ be a quadratic form, i.e. $q(a)=q(-a)$ and $b(x,y)=q(x+y)-q(x)-q(y)$ is a bihomomorphism. On vector spaces, when people speak about the kernel of a quadratic form they mean the radical of $\frac{b}{2}$ which is obviously not possible here, at least not straight-forwardly. Taking the radical of $b$ itself is not sufficient since in general we don't have a quadratic form $\bar{q}:G/\mathrm{Rad}(b) \to \mathbb{Q/Z}$, s.t. $\pi^*\bar{q}=q$ (for example let $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $q(n)=\frac{n}{2} + \mathbb{Z}$). Hence my question:

Is there some definition/construction of the kernel of quadratic forms on abelian groups?

Comment: What property should the kernel $K$ have?  The end of your first paragraph suggests you might want something like $K$ being minimal with respect to the requirement that there is a quadratic form $\bar q$ on $G/K$ that pulls back to $q$.  Is that, together presumably with some sort of uniqueness, correct?  (Also, a notational suggestion: old-fashioned texts often used $[\cdot]$ for the greatest-integer function, so $q(n) = n/2 + \mathbb Z$ might be clearer than $q(n) = [n/2]$.)

Comment: @LSpice Correct!

Comment: A "kernel" can be defined for an arbitrary map $f$ from an abelian group $G$ to a set $X$, namely $K=\{g:\forall g':f(g'+g)=f(g')\}$. Thus $G/K_G$ is the largest quotient group of $G$ through which $f$ factors. This extends the usual kernel of quadratic maps on vector spaces.

Comment: @YCor Thx, that makes sense. Using the above notation the factor map $\bar{q}$ should be again a quadratic form since the quotient map $\pi$ is an epimorphism, right? Still I would like to have a more 'compact' description of this group, but I first need to make up my mind about what I mean by that..

Comment: In the theory of quadratic forms over a field of characteristic 2, the radical of a quadratic form $q$ is sometimes defined as $R(q)=\{x\in \mathrm{rad}(b):q(x)=0\}$, where $b$ is the polar form of $q$. This should work in your situation as well: $R(q)$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $q$ factors via a $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$-quadratic map on $G/R(q)$. (This should coincide with @YCor's suggestion, but is perhaps conceptually clearer.)

Comment: Ah, so its the (usual) kernel of $q|_{\operatorname{rad(b)}}$ as $q$ is a homomorphism on $\operatorname{rad(b)}$

Comment: @UriyaFirst and Ycor: Perhaps leave this as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: Can I recommend Ed Brown's paper, "Generalizations of the Kervaire invariant," especially theorem 1.20 in that paper. I learned a great deal about quadratic forms and the prime two from this paper, especially the fact that there is a mod 8 invariant and a Gauß sum that computes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, I post my comment (with mild changes) as answer:

In the theory of quadratic forms over a field of characteristic $2$, the radical of a quadratic form $q$ is sometimes defined as $R(q)=\{x\in \mathrm{rad}(b):q(x)=0\}$, where $b$ is the polar form of $q$. This should work in your situation as well: $R(q)$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $q$ factors via a $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$-valued quadratic map on $G/R(q)$.

The subgroup $R(q)$ should coincide with the kernel suggested in @YCor's comment.